# Stopping a windows service via program

Tags: c#, windows-services, system

Programmatically stopping a windows service in c# generates below listed `System.InvalidOperationException`

{Access is denied}

If i start/stop through windows interface then everything works fine!
I'm an Admin user and running the service under Windows 7

Comment: Please insert the code that you use to stop the service in your question.

Comment: What account is the program that is stopping the service running under?

Comment: What kind of account is the service log on? (Shown on the right click->properties menu from Services.msc)

Comment: if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{
  service.Stop();
  service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
}

service is instaled as to run under Local Service Account

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are trying to stop it, but I tried this on my system now, and this approach at least works fine:

```
var p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
          FileName = "net",
          Arguments = "stop NameOfService",
          CreateNoWindow = true,
          WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        });
p.WaitForExit(); //add this line if you want to make sure that the service is stopped before your program execution continues
```

Comment: Is your Visual Studio running in Admininstrator Mode? Because my `net start`/`net stop` do need UAC approval.

Comment: once the service is deployed, it runs fine, but when servicecontroller .stop command executes i get the exception System.InvalidOperationException

the service need to be executed on daily basis at predefined time, so thats why i want to stop it once the necessary process completes

Comment: @Lucero - Yup, my VS is running in Administrator Mode.

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen Does it still work when you run it directly from Windows Explorer, and not from within VS?

Comment: if i start/stop manually everything works fine!

only problem is when i try to stop the service programatically using



if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running) { service.Stop(); service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped); }

Comment: @Lucero - My program is actually used for updating the service. So the service itself starts the application, then the application shuts down the service, updates it and restarts it. This works just fine. The service runs as the `Local System` user.

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen: Yes, of course this scenario works because the service runs in an elevated context and the programs it starts therefore also run in that context. The point is that it wouldn't work if executed from Windows Explorer or a normal (unelevated) command prompt.

Comment: how to run my windows service code under elevated privileges @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen

Comment: i tried the above approach mentioned by you @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen, but the service isnt stopping, so finally i had to manually stop it. am trying by turning off UAC now.

Comment: thanks a lot @Lucero, finally am resorting to using a bat file to stop and start the service and doing away with pro-grammatically stopping the service as i couldn't get any proper solution

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a UAC issue - try running the application which shall control the service as admin (right-click, "Run as Administrator").

Note that even an administrator account does not have full privileges unless you explicitly run applications in administrator mode - this was introduced for protecting the user from malicious software in Windows Vista and has been there since then.

Comment: hi there

i have tried the UAC approach by creating a manifest file, also am aware that in Win 7 even a admin user is treated as standard user unless until one says run as, but this approach is wherein user intervenes to start stop the service

i want the service to be stopped programatically

Comment: @prashant, well, the whole point of UAC is to prevent software from doing critical things (and stopping services is one of them - stopping the firewall service of some antivirus service is lowering the machine's security). So unless your users approve to run your software it will not be allowed to control services. That said, you could have the service stop itself and just send a "message" to your service to tell it to shut itself down.

Comment: i didnt get what you said in last sentence

security wise as of now its ok, as it will execute on a standalone server.


"you could have the service stop itself and just send a "message" to your service to tell it to shut itself down"

Comment: @prashant, the service does typically have enough privileges to shut itself down. Therefore, if you somehow "tell" the service, for instance via a message sent to a mailslot, to shut itself down, your application could control the shutdown of the service by this means.

Comment: @prashant - To see if this is the problem, just temporarily shut down the UAC and see if your program behaves as expected with UAC turned off.

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen didnt help by turning off the UAC, i got the same exception over again
how to assign higher permission levels to a service controller

this is the detailed exception from windows event log
Application: TransferService.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
Stack:
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServiceHandle(Int32)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Stop()

Comment: thanks a lot @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen, finally am resorting to using a bat file to stop and start the service and doing away with pro-grammatically stopping the service as i couldn't get any proper solution

Answer (score 0):

If authentication is the problem ...

You can programatically control the user from which you're doing stuff with, using

```
WindowsIdentity
```

and

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool LogonUser(...)
```

I don't know if that would work, but it could be worth a shot.

```
IntPtr token IntPtr.Zero;
LogonUser(username, password ..., ref token) //and some other parameters
var identity = WindowsIdentity(token);

using(identity.Impersonate())
{ 
    //do stuff here using another identity
    //find service and stop it
}
```

edit: This can be used for authentication on remote servers.

Comment: i would probably not opt for impersonation, am  using a external .bat file to stop and start the service instead of working it out pro-grammatically, and that solves my purpose!

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I saw that before I posted, still wanted to share this approach for others though.